# optimised combined area of a rectangle and a square

Tags: calculus, optimization, area

Consider a rectangle of dimensions $2x$ by $x$ and a square of dimensions $y$ by $y$. If the sum of the perimeters of the rectangle and square is $l$, find the value of $x$ and $y$ (in terms of $l$) that minimise the sum of areas of the rectangle and the square.

What I found on the internet are solutions where the rectangle and the square share one dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2x^2 + y^2 = A$

$6 x + 4 y = l$

so

$y = \frac{l - 6 x}{4}$

Thus $A = 2 x^2 + \left( \frac{l - 6 x}{4}\right)^2$

Expand... take the derivative with respect to $x$, set it to zero to find the minimizing (or maximizing) $x$.

Comment: A = (2x^2 + l^2 - 12x + 36x^2)/16 = (38x^2 - 12x)/16 + l^2/16, A' = (79x -12)/16 + 0, x = 12/79 , A'' = (79/16 > 0 => min   y= (l -6*12/79)/4 = (79l -72)/316

This is right? Thanks

Comment: So maybe an accept ($\checkmark$) or at least a (+1) seems in order.

Answer (score 0):

You have given $$6x+4y=l$$ and to optimize the function
$$f(x,y)=2x^2+y^2$$ with $$y=\frac{l-6x}{4}$$ you will get
$$f\left(x,\frac{l-6x}{4}\right)=2x^2+\left(\frac{l-6x}{4}\right)^2$$
Can you proceed?